# Scrivener: marking multiple (non-adjacent) phrases in a manuscript with same footnote

Tags: tools, footnotes, scrivener

How can I mark multiple different non-adjacent words and/or phrases with the same endnote marker and the same endnote text in Scrivener?

For example:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, **consectetuer adipiscing** elit, sed diam
>   nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat
>   volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation
>   ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
>   Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse
>   molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at
>   vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent
>   luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.
>   Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil
>   imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non
>   habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum
>   claritatem. Investigationes **demonstraverunt lectores** legere me
>   lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus,
>   qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam
>   littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit
>   litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta
>   decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant
>   sollemnes in futurum.

I want to mark both bold phrases in the text above using the endnote marker, "1" (as a superscript following each bold phrase) and create only a single endnote number 1 at the end of the (short; maybe 3-4 page) manuscript.

When I try to do this in Scrivener and print to PDF, Scrivener assigns different endnote numbers to each bold phrase even though the endnote text is identical, and just creates two identical endnotes at the bottom of the page, numbered 1 and 2.

If the PDF format won't handle something like that, then RTF is ok with me too, but my trouble is telling Scrivener that this is what I want to do.

Although this manuscript is short (2-4 pages) and I could probably do this in a word processor, I really like Scrivener's many little touches that make the documents it produces unique. This document is for a job application and I'm trying to impress in as many subtle ways as possible.

I should also add something I wrote in a comment below which is that endnote symbols (dagger, double-dagger, et. al.) would suffice too, but my main problem is how to get Scrivener to render the footnote/endnote horizontal rule other than by marking text with a footnote/endnote?

When I print-to-PDF a document containing footnotes or endnotes in Scrivener, the PDF produces this very nice horizontal rule across about 1/3 of the bottom of the page to separate the footnotes from the main text.

My question is, can I manually insert such a horizontal rule? [RTF seems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1929364/rtf-line-separator) to [allow for that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8324801/richtextbox-draw-an-rtf-line), but I can't get any of the solutions mentioned here to render the line when I do print-to-PDF. I have the same problem when I use OS X TextEdit.App (which I had previously thought was a full-featured RTF editor that implemented the entire RTF specification).

Plus, I don't really know how to insert raw RTF into the Scrivener editor. My attempts above may have failed because I worked around this limitation in my knowledge by closing the Scrivener project and then using vim to edit the rtf files manually, inserting the RTF code to produce a horizontal rule. Maybe this risks corrupting the Scrivener project, not sure, but I know of no other way to insert raw RTF code into the editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I would reconsider marking it with the same footnote marker, and rather mark them as 1 and 2, with the 2nd one consisting of the word "Ibid." [Ibid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibid.) means "the same place", and is "used to provide an endnote or footnote citation or reference for a source that was cited in the preceding endnote or footnote".

If you reference the same source more than once, but they're not together, the first footnote should be formatted formally with the full citation, but the second and subsequent footnotes can be abbreviated to a short form. Check your style guide, but for the most part, using Surname, Title, Page should suffice.

**Edit:** Based on your comments, one possible solution to avoid having to manually keep track of Ibids and Op Cits is for you to handle your citations using [Zotero](http://www.zotero.org/) (free and open source, I believe). Although I don't personally use it, there is this blog post which describes [how you can integrate Zotero and Scrivener](http://mossiso.com/2012/04/12/scrivener-and-zotero.html). As the last paragraph states:

> One alternative method is to create footnotes in Scrivener using the format {Author, Year, Page#}. Then export as an RTF document as before. Then, in Zotero, use the ‘RTF Scan’ tool in the Preferences menu. Zotero will see all of the citations and replace them nicely with formatted citations (using Ibid. and short notation for repeat books, and such). Zotero will not be aware of these citations at all, so if you need them to be Zotero aware, you might as well use the steps outlined above. If you do not expect to update citations or the text once done in Scrivener, then this may be the easiest way to go.

Comment: Thats a good point although I should have mentioned that I'm not following any particular style guide. I'm looking to attribute multiple different quotations to the same source in the least amount of physical space. I suppose I should do that with endnotes rather than footnotes, so I'll edit my post to reflect that. I'd also be happy to have the footnote numbers be symbols (dagger, double-dagger, et. al.) instead of numbers per se. My main goal is to get Scrivener to render the footnote horizontal rule which I don't know how to do manually. My text is short enough that I don't need automation.

Comment: I tried this just to see how much extra vertical space the Ibids would add, and it's significant. Plus, I guess I have to manually keep track of the Ibids and Op Cits this way? Or does Scrivener allow me to automate that chore so if I move text around, I don't have to re-evaluate the accuracy of all the Ibids and Op Cits?

Comment: I don't believe Scrivener will keep track of the Ibids and Op Cits, but could be wrong as I'm not 100% sure. However, did some digging around and found a possible solution for you, which I've appended to my answer.

Comment: Well, keeping track of Ibids and Op cits is only necessary if I start using Ibids. I have 4 sources that I quote 16 times, so using Ibids I'll be adding an additional 12 lines (plus interline spacing). What I'd really like to do is just add a footnote horizontal rule to separate the main body of the document from the 4 footnote/endnote references and either use daggers and other symbols or else use numbers as footnote markers, but having only 4 sources, I think that Ibids is much more complex than I really need.

Comment: I ended up solving this using TeXShop and LaTeX and a bunch of packages. I appreciate your suggestion, though. Would be nice to figure out a way to do this in Scrivener.